# Oracle APEX Dynamic Action PageLoad Processing

Tags: dynamic, action, oracle-apex, pageload, oracle-apex-5

**Situation**: I currently have a page that is a type of Dashboard page. It contains several charts and reports. This page is the home page of the application. When the page first loads a Request Type of First is passed into the page. As the page renders several page processes calling Oracle Package, setting values, etc are executed. Once the page processes are complete, i believe the dynamic actions are then fired off. There are probably 10 DA's that are fired on PageLoad. The very first DA is fires on PageLoad but has a condition of REQUEST = 'First'. If condition is met, the page is then resubmitted with a Request Type of: search.

**Question**: How does APEX process Dynamic Actions, specifically PageLoad? If there are 10 Dynamic Actions all sequences are greater then another, does APEX or Page Processing handle one at a time or do they all execute at the same time regardless of sequence and conditions?

**Reason for Question:** I created a DA to execute an insert statement into a DB Table. This DA executes on page load with no conditions and is sequence#: 0. Then, i created another DA to do the same but is the very last sequence#. When logged into the application and then viewed the data inserted into the DB table, it showed both records 4 times. the first two were inserted when request type = First. Then the DA already mentioned fired and resubmitted the page which then inserted two more records. I was only expecting three records to be in the DB Table. One for the request type First and two for the request type search.

Comment: Have you looked at the debug log? Can you post a sample application? I suspect that the conditions of your DAs aren't proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using dynamic actions? Why not use processes that execute during page render?

Dynamic action execute order can't be guaranteed in that way, in the same way has a JavaScript loop behaves like nothing you'd think. JavaScript does it's own thing.

If you're executing PL/SQL in your dynamic actions, this will behave synchronously or asynchronously. Either way, they will be launched with x separate processes. The only way to control order would be to have them in the same dynamic action and 'wait for result' set to yes.

Which brings me back to: why use dynamic actions?

Comment: How would you resubmit the page from a page process if you do not use dynamic actions? Items need to be set with values the first time the page loads. Once those items have values, then the page resubmits to run queries based on those item values. Also, I didn't develop this... I inherited it and I want to improve the performance of the page. I do not like the dynamic action to resubmit the page because it adds about 2 to 3 seconds on to the page load time.Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: Instead of resubmitting the page can't you refresh the necessary regions? With Ajax calls you'll not need to resubmit the page.

Comment: FYI, I figured out a way to resubmit the page from page processing. I did a redirect_url call and passed the new request type. This suggestion of not using a dynamic action seemed to have improved the performance of the page load. Thanks for the suggestion. If you have any other tips for speeding up page load i would love to read about them.

Comment: @hmarques, I am not farmiliar with AJAX calls. Could you provide an example of how i would implement an AJAX call to refresh a region?

Comment: You can refresh a region by adding an ID to it and just running this js: $('#<YOUR_REGION_ID>').trigger('apexrefresh');

Comment: .trigger() is the same as having a Refresh action in a dynamic action.

Comment: The basic premise to think about is - can these procedures be invoked while the page is being rendered, or do you *really* need to wait until the HTML has been generated and displayed? It really sounds like you're going against the grain for a normal web app.